# Audio clip recorder for website

Tags: javascript, flash

On the client side of my website i want to be able to allow the user to record a short audio clip, around 20 seconds duration and store this recorded audio on the server.
Is there any way to do this using any client side technologies like javascript or flash ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a small flash application that enables users to record audio from their computer, but you will need some kind of server script that takes the recorded audio, and saves it on the server.